How to create a loop in a liquid loop?
I wrote code that worked flawlessly, but the next day everything broke. Did the inner loop now output the same number of elements as in the first one? What am I doing wrong?
{%- assign category_names = site.data.list_of_sections_with_categories.yagodnye-kultury -%}

{%- for post in site.posts limit: 3 %}
  {%- for list_of_categories in category_names -%}
   {%- if post.categories contains list_of_categories -%}
   {%- include /second-section-item-1-test.html -%}
{%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
{% endfor %}


It must be like this:

category1
category2
category3

it turns out like this:

category1
category1
category1
category1
category2
category2
category2
...........


First remove all the - before and after the percentage symbol %
Did you add more than a single category to your posts after you did your modifications?
To get what you want, switch the first two for loops, and add {% break %} after the {% include %} line.

`{% assign category_names = site.data.list_of_sections_with_categories.yagodnye-kultury %}
{% for list_of_categories in category_names %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% if post.categories contains list_of_categories %}
{% include /short-review.html %}
{% break %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}`
This code didn't work either. It turns out that in the first cycle we get a list from "yagodnye-kultury", there are three positions. In the second cycle we get all the posts of the site. The output is that all the posts of the site are displayed three times.

They key part is the break statement; once a post category is matched, you want to break so that the post is not printed more than once. Try switching the for loops again.

please watch this video
